# Scrollbar duplicate winapi c++

Tags: c++, winapi, scrollbar

I am making a scrollbar for the first time and don't understand why I have a duplicate of my scrollbar when content is scrollable.
Here is how it looks, I don't know if you can see it good enough but here's a screenshot; one scrollbar is the thick gray one (the one a want to keep, looks more like the classic scrollbar), and one is a little gray rectangle to the left of it. Both of these scrollbars work and scroll my program.
:

[image: Double scroll]

But when content is not scrollable then it looks like this:

[image]

Here is my ScrollBar.cpp if this will help:

```
#include "ScrollBar.h"

ScrollBar::ScrollBar(){}

ScrollBar::~ScrollBar(){
    RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, scrollProc, IDC_STATIC);
    delete con;
}


ScrollBar::ScrollBar(HWND hWnd, HINSTANCE hInst) : hWnd(hWnd),hInst(hInst) {
    this->hWndParent = GetParent(hWnd);
    con = new Controls(hWndParent);
}

void ScrollBar::createScroll(int x, int y, int w, int h, bool stickRight, bool stickBottom) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->width = w;
    this->height = h;

    hScroll = con->create("scrollbar", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SBS_VERT, x, y, width, height,"scrollBar","",0, stickRight, stickBottom);
    //Creates like this
    /// CreateWindowEx(0, type, text, styles, cData.x, cData.y, cData.width, cData.height, hWnd, (HMENU)id, NULL, (LPVOID)lParam);

    SetWindowSubclass(hScroll, scrollProc, IDC_STATIC, (DWORD_PTR)this);
    SetWindowSubclass(hWndParent, scrollProc, IDC_STATIC, (DWORD_PTR)this);

    con->setEventListener();
}


void ScrollBar::setScrollRange(int scrollMaxHeight) {
    scrollMaxH = scrollMaxHeight == -1 ? scrollMaxH : scrollMaxHeight;
    SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
    si.fMask = SIF_RANGE;
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = scrollMaxH;

    SetScrollInfo(hScroll, SB_VERT, &si, false);

}


void ScrollBar::setScrollSize() {

    SCROLLINFO oSi = { 0 };
    oSi.cbSize = sizeof(oSi);
    oSi.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS;
    GetScrollInfo(hScroll, SB_VERT, &oSi);


    RECT rect = GetLocalCoordinates(hWnd);
    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;



    SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };

    si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
    si.fMask = SIF_PAGE;
    si.nPage = height;

    SetScrollInfo(hScroll, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);

    si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS;

    GetScrollInfo(hScroll, SB_VERT, &si);

    int res = oSi.nPos - si.nPos;

    if (res > 0) {

        setChildScrollOffset(hWnd, res);
    }
}


void ScrollBar::handleVScroll(int action,int thum) {
    int nPos;
    int nOldPos;

    SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };

    si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
    si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS;
    GetScrollInfo(hScroll, SB_VERT, &si);

    nOldPos = si.nPos;

    switch (action)
    {
    case SB_TOP:
        nPos = si.nMin;
        break;

    case SB_BOTTOM:
        nPos = si.nMax;
        break;

    case SB_LINEUP:
        nPos = si.nPos - 30;
        break;

    case SB_LINEDOWN:
        nPos = si.nPos + 30;
        break;

    case SB_PAGEUP:
        nPos = si.nPos - 30;
        break;

    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
        nPos = si.nPos + 30;
        break;

    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
        nPos = thum;
        break;

    default:
        nPos = si.nPos;
        break;
    }

    SetScrollPos(hScroll, SB_VERT, nPos, TRUE);

    nPos = GetScrollPos(hScroll, SB_VERT);


    if (nOldPos != nPos) {
        ScrollWindowEx(hWnd, 0, nOldPos - nPos, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
            SW_INVALIDATE | SW_ERASE | SW_SCROLLCHILDREN);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);
        setChildScrollOffset(hWnd, nOldPos - nPos);
    }
}

void ScrollBar::setChildScrollOffset(HWND h, int offset) {
    Controls* childsCon = reinterpret_cast<Controls*>(GetWindowLongPtr(h, GWLP_USERDATA));
    for (auto it : childsCon->sControls)
    {
        childsCon->getControlItem(it.first)->y += offset;
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ScrollBar::scrollProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    ScrollBar* lpData = (ScrollBar*)dwRefData;

    HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HBRUSH hbrBackground;


    switch (uMsg) {
    
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        lpData->setScrollSize();
        break;
    }
    case WM_VSCROLL:
    {
        lpData->handleVScroll(LOWORD(wParam), HIWORD(wParam));
        return true;
    }
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    {

        short zDelta = (short)(0xFFFF & (wParam >> 16));
        if (zDelta > 0)
            PostMessage(lpData->hScroll, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, NULL);
        else
            PostMessage(lpData->hScroll, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: [There are two types of scrollbars](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040510-00/?p=39413).

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I am blind and so can't see your screen shots but does your parent window have WS_VSCROLL? (you don't show the styles associated with that window). If so remove it, the WS_VSCROLL adds a scrollbar that is not control-based to the window's non-client area.

Comment: No, the only styles parent has is "WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE" but I just noticed that a duplicate scroll shows up after I use "MoveWindow" function with the HWND of the scroll

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between [Standard Scroll Bars and Scroll Bar Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-scroll-bars#standard-scroll-bars-and-scroll-bar-controls). A scroll bar control is a control window that belongs to the SCROLLBAR window class.

For more details about how to Create Scroll Bar, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [How to Create Scroll Bars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-scroll-bars)

According to the code, you want to create a Scroll Bar Controls. So you should creates a window without standard horizontal and vertical scroll bars and then use the CreateWindowEx function to create a scroll bar by specifying the SCROLLBAR window class.

Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample?